# Rating system for zero-sum games that has good theoretical properties compared to Elo rating?

Tags: scoring-rules, elo

The Elo rating system is widely used in two-player zero-sum games/sports like Chess. It is not obvious to me that the Elo rating system is has the "nicest" theoretical properties out of all conceivable rating systems. As an example, Microsoft's [TrueSKill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueSkill) takes into account uncertainty about the players' skill level (side-note: it is a bit bizarre to me that an algorithm as simple as TrueSkill, essentially just an approximation of bayesian inference, has been patented). Nevertheless TrueSkill still seems somewhat ad-hoc to me.

Is there a (set of) rating system(s) for zero-sum games that have provably good theoretical properties? I am not interested in practical constraints. For example, we can assume that we have access to the entire set of games ever played (containing the identifier of each player, the time it was played, the score achieved), and that computation-cost is not an issue.

Comment: The Elo rating system is based on the odds of winning being multiplicative transitive between players, in the sense that (in a win-lose competition) if the predicted odds of A beating B are $3:1$ and the predicted odds of B beating C are $5:1$ then the predicted odds of A beating C are $15:1$.  Is that a "nice theoretical property"? The second part of the Elo rating system is updating ratings on the basis of evidence, aiming to reduce errors in predicted odds over time while avoiding excessive volatility in ratings.

Comment: @Henry, this is an assumption that is restricts the applicability of the rating system, so I would call it a "not super nice" theoretical property. I didn't want to commit to any particular properties, because I'm open to whatever people have actually managed to develop.

Comment: @Henry, But examples of nice theoretical properties are: (1) For a pool of non-learning players (e.g. a pool of algorithms that don't change between games), when matching them according to current score estimates (via some specific rule), their ratings converge in probability to a fixed value (rather than e.g. there being cycles in scores). (2) That probabilistic limit is relatively robust to changes in the distribution of player matchups. E.g. if two pools A,B mostly play each other, but with some interaction, the ratings are not very different from if they played eachother uniformly

Comment: Note the last one is at least somewhat violated by Elo under the assumption that odds of winning are not multiplicatively transitive.

Comment: @user56834 You must define what population is competing against each other with Elo. If there were a separate Elo for only children, a child might obtain 2,500 Elo. However, if they played a grandmaster adult, they would lose severely. People make this error when discussing the Elo of chess engines. Their Elos were determined in tournaments of chess engines. To figure out Stockfish's human Elo, you'd have to have humans play it 10,000s of times. Since the chances of the human winning are slim to none, you might even need 100,000s until you get enough black swan event victories to know the Elo.